# Running SQL command with powershell issue

Tags: sql, powershell, vbscript

I have the following powershell command i have converted from VB script:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(“Data Source=SERVER; Initial Catalog=DATABASE; Integrated Security=SSPI”) 
$conn.Open() 
$cmd1 = $conn.CreateCommand() 
$cmd1.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text 
$cmd1.CommandText =“SELECT guid, name, [Serial Number] FROM dbo.wrksta as a inner join Inv_AeX_HW_Serial_Number as b on a.GUID=b._resourceGUID ORDER BY Name” 
$data = $cmd1.ExecuteReader() 
$cmd2 = $conn.CreateCommand() 
$cmd2.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text 
$cmd2.CommandText =“SELECT top 1 [User] FROM dbo.Evt_aex_client_logon WHERE _resourceGuid = (SELECT top 1 Guid FROM dbo.Wrksta WHERE Name='" + $data["name"] + "' ORDER BY WrkstaID DESC) AND Event = 'logon' AND _eventTime > getdate()-60 GROUP BY [User] ORDER BY count([User]) desc” 
$data2 = $cmd2.ExecuteReader() 
$dt = new-object “System.Data.DataTable” 
$dt.Load($data2) 
$dt | format-table 
$conn.Close()
```

If you look at the second select statement I am wanting to use a value from the first variable $data but im unsure how to write it. in VB it was like this WHERE Name='" + workstation("name").value + "' is the following the correct way to write this in powershell? '" + $data["name"] + "'. Im after the value from the name column stored in the $date variable

The VB used to do this previously is below

```
connString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
objSQL.Open connString 

sqlWorkstations = "SELECT guid, name, [Serial Number] FROM dbo.wrksta as a inner join Inv_AeX_HW_Serial_Number as b on a.GUID=b._resourceGUID ORDER BY Name"
Set workstation = objSQL.Execute(sqlWorkstations)

Do Until (workstation.EOF)

sqlUser = "SELECT top 1 [User] FROM dbo.Evt_aex_client_logon WHERE _resourceGuid = (SELECT top 1 Guid FROM dbo.Wrksta WHERE Name='" + workstation("name").value + "' ORDER BY WrkstaID DESC) AND Event = 'logon' AND _eventTime > getdate()-60 GROUP BY [User] ORDER BY count([User]) desc"
set user = objSQL.Execute(sqlUser)

if not user.eof then
  userName = user("User").value
else
  username = "??????"
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make things a lot easier on yourself and load the `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100` snap-in. If you're dealing with SQL Server, it handles most of the boilerplate for you and distills running queries to a single cmdlet.

Your code above assumes that the first query returns only a single row. This may or may not always be the case; I don't know your database. If it returns multiple records, then your code will only give you data corresponding to the first record from the first query.

Using `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100`'s `Invoke-SQLCmd` and handling the case of multiple records being returned, do this:

```
$data1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance SERVER -Database DATABASE -Query “SELECT guid, name, [Serial Number] FROM dbo.wrksta as a inner join Inv_AeX_HW_Serial_Number as b on a.GUID=b._resourceGUID ORDER BY Name”;
foreach ($row in $data1) {
    $name = $row.name;
    $data2 = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance SERVER -Database DATABASE -Query “SELECT top 1 [User] FROM dbo.Evt_aex_client_logon WHERE _resourceGuid = (SELECT top 1 Guid FROM dbo.Wrksta WHERE Name='$name' ORDER BY WrkstaID DESC) AND Event = 'logon' AND _eventTime > getdate()-60 GROUP BY [User] ORDER BY count([User]) desc” ;
    $data2 |ft -AutoSize
}
```

It's also possible that you could retrieve all of your data with a single properly-written query but again, without knowing the data that's hard to say. You really ought to consult with your DBA regarding these queries to make sure they're written properly and match your requirements properly.

Comment: Thats great, how do I get/register this sql snapin on a server without SQL as the script does a lot of other bits too. by the way the first query will return around 400-500 records. I have added the VB used previously to do this job.

Comment: You need to install SQL Server Management Studio to get the snap-in. It's worth it - IMHO you shouldn't ever re-invent something that someone else has written and made available. In this case, that's Invoke-SQLCmd vs. the code you ported from VB.Net.

Comment: Even with the first query returning 400-500 records, you may be able to do the work of both of these queries with a single, better-written query. And possibly reduce load on the server & improve execution time/memory footprint of your script.

Comment: what version(s) are powershell aware is it 2008+?

Comment: I think so. Invoke-SQLCmd can query servers at least as old as 2000 though. Install the current/latest SSMS and you'll be OK.

Comment: You can also go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) to grab SQL 2012's Powershell module. It feels a little nicer to me than the older style snapins, and it works even though I use SSMS 2008 against a SQL 2008 database. Install 3 components: CLR Types, Shared Management Objects and then Powershell Extensions. Then just `Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

[ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) only creates the reader, but you need to call $data.Read() to retrieve the first record. (see sample in linked MSDN)